# Display a php form in colorbox

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the colorbox jquery plugin and I'd like to display a PHP form in the colorbox.

```
<?php if( is_array($pages_created) ){ ?>    

    <form id="link_page_form" method="post" action="my_url" >
        <select id="page_from_link" name="page_from_id" >
            <OPTION VALUE="" >Associate with:</OPTION>              
                <?php foreach($pages_created as $k) {  ?>                       
                    <OPTION id="<?php echo $k[3] ?>" VALUE="<?php echo $k[0]; ?>" ><?php echo $k[1]; ?></OPTION>            
                <?php } ?>  
        </select>   

        <button type="submit" >OK</button>
    </form> 
<?php } ?>
```

What should I do to make that possible ?
( $("#link_page_form").colorbox(); doesn't work )

Comment: do you get any errors..?

Comment: Where do you put `$("#link_page_form").colorbox();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#some_anchor_id").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#link_page_form"});
});
```

Hope it helps